# Open Facebook Fanpage Album intent?

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent

i have a problem with intent in Android Studio,

i want to open a Fanpage Album  with Facebook app from my application.

i tried to use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://album/110994529613954?owner=109409633105777"));
                    startActivity(intent);
```

and i can only use this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://facewebmodal/f?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F109409633105777%2Fphotos%2F%3Ftab%3Dalbum%26album_id%3D110994529613954"));
                        startActivity(intent);
```

but i want to open album without facewebmodal :/